# Get max bucket of terms aggregation (with pipeline aggregation)

Tags: elasticsearch

I was wondering how to get the bucket with the highest doc_count when using a `terms` aggregation with Elasticsearch. I'm using the Kibana sample data *kibana_sample_data_flights:*

```
GET kibana_sample_data_flights/_search
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "destinations": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "DestCityName"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

If there was a single bucket with the max `doc_count` value I could set the `size` of the terms aggregation to 1, however this doesn't work if there are two buckets with the same max `doc_count` value.

Since I came accross pipeline aggregations, I feel there should be an easy way to achieve this. The max bucket aggregation seems to be able to deal with multiple max buckets, since the guide says this:

> [...] which identifies the bucket(**s**) with the maximum value of [...]

However the only way to make this work was using a work-around with a sub-aggregation using `value_count`:

```
GET kibana_sample_data_flights/_search
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "destinations": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "DestCityName"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "counter": {
          "value_count": {
            "field": "_id"
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "max_destination": {
      "max_bucket": {
        "buckets_path": "destinations>counter"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

---

a) Is there a better way in general, to find the terms bucket with the max value?

b) Is there a better way using pipeline aggrations?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well you can simplify as below and you don't need to make use of [`value_count`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-metrics-valuecount-aggregation.html) aggregation.

However, unfortunately using [`max_bucket`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-pipeline-max-bucket-aggregation.html) is the only way to get what you are looking for.

```
POST <your_index_name>/_search
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "destinations": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "DestCityName"
      }
    },
    "max_destination": {
      "max_bucket": {
        "buckets_path": "destinations>_count"       <---- Note the usage of _count
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Hope this helps!